# JSP cannot find css files while using ResourceHandlerRegistry.addResourceHandler (Java based webConfig)

Tags: java, html, css, spring, jsp

This is where i put my css file:

[image]

This is how i register this resource:

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
     registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

This is how i references this css from the JSP:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

**I can see the JSP page with content but without styling.**

I think the error is while referencing but i cant find it. I have tried also these, but does not work:

```
<link type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link type="text/css" href="/resources/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link type="text/css" href="<%=request.getContextPath() %>/resources/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Any idea?

**EDIT:** Now i have moved the css folder to WebContent. It seems like this:

[image]

It still does not work. What should i register for the ResourceHandler?

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/WEB-INF/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/"); ?
```

How should i reference the css from the JSP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource handler doesn't look for resources on the class path, by default. It looks for them in the webapp.

Create a folder called `resources` and put it in `/src/main/webapp`. Then put your `css`, `js`, etc. folders in there.

Comment: _The resource handler doesn't look for resources on the class path, by default_ I dont understand what the "default" is. registry.addResourceHandler is just for that reason there, so that any file on the build path can be registered..

Comment: @Cimbom Where are your jsps? Those should typically be in the `WEB-INF` folder which is inside `webcontent` . With maven, you use `src/main/webapp` instead of `webcontent`.

Comment: @Cimbom If you want to specify files in the build path, the resource location needs to be prefixed with `classpath:`. I don't think that is a good idea.

Comment: I am using maven and i have a webContent folder. Please look at the question. I updated it. And please define a concrete solution.

Comment: @Cimbom Leave your original resource registration as is. Create a `src/main/webapp` folder. In eclipse, add it to the build path. It is now a source folder. Add a folder called `resources` to it. Move your `css` folder from `src/main/resources` to `src/main/webapp/resources`.

Answer (score 1):

The files under src cannot be accessed on default condition , you should put these assets into WebContent directory.

---

Resources usually means config proppertis like properties and xml, they will be used by the 
java code, assets usually mean that can be accessed by the browser directly,Notice that WEB-INF is protected,you need to put your css directory under WebContent, except for  **WEB-INF**

for exampel,you can put your css directory under `/WebContent/assets/`

And add these code at the head of your jsp pages

```
<%
String basePath = request.getScheme() + "://"
        + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort()
        + request.getContextPath();
%>

<link type="text/css" href="<%=basePath%>/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

**It's not good to use relative path!!**

Comment: I dont understand what the "default condition" is. registry.addResourceHandler is just for that reason there, so that any file on the build path can be registered..

Comment: Your last suggestion does not work. href seems like this "http://localhost:8080/projectName/assets/css/bootstrap.css" and the file not found.  Also this should be made in another way, where you do not have to define a basePath. Since we are using Spring here, we should easily be able to register the css files, and these files should be reached easily just like the jsp file itself. I do not think that every JSP page in the application must define or need this constant basePath.

Comment: Ok. When i add the assess folder as resource, it works.  registry.addResourceHandler("/assets/**").addResourceLocations("/assets/**"). I am trying to get rid of this basePath now..

Comment: href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css". Without basePath. It works.

Comment: maybe **WEB-INF** is protected, even spring resource handler cannot access it. LOL

Comment: the `../` stands for parent dir, if your springmvc action is like 'http://localhost:8080/ProjectName/customer/profile/XX.do`, it will not work well.

Comment: For this example my current URL is "http://localhost:8080/projectName/item/showAllItems" and it works..